# g++ Difference Between Bash For Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, windows, ubuntu, c++17

Simple question: Why is the version of g++ lower in the Bash For Windows subsystem than in Ubuntu proper?

Complicated question: Is there a way to fast forward the version of g++ on the Bash For Windows subsystem to what is pushed to normal Ubuntu systems?

Specifically, this question is stemming out of my need to use the c++17 filesystem implementation/support:
With the same compile command (`g++ -Wall -std=c++1y main.cpp -o main`), the same file will not compile on Windows but will in Ubuntu:

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>

int main() {}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: if it compiles in Ubuntu you could try cross-compiling for windows?

Comment: In theory, you could use the current compiler to bootstrap the version you want, maybe as new as g++ 7.1.  In practice, that may be tricky.

Comment: [Bash For Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about) (and [their GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft)) is experimental and maintained by Microsoft. Microsoft does not keep things up to date like they could. For example, the [Microsoft port of OpenSSL](https://github.com/Microsoft) is still behind what OpenSSL recommends. Microsoft recently moved from 1.0.1 to 1.0.2.

Comment: @Makogan, the Linux subsystem is just most convenient to use for compiling... It's not a matter of the target system, but more-so for not having to spin up a VM on a machine that can't run Linux naively.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel and jww, it seems that since they're so behind, that might be the best way to go.. Post a mini guide as an answer and I'll mark it as the accepted answer?

Comment: A quick guide for compiling newer gcc on WSL can be found here: https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/05/04/building-gcc-wsl-windows-subsystem-linux/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by in the comments of the original post, g++ in the Linux For Windows Subsystem is maintained by Windows, [here](https://github.com/Microsoft), and is not as current as it could possibly be..  So, to compile a newer version of gcc for the Linux Subsystem, [this](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/05/04/building-gcc-wsl-windows-subsystem-linux/) guide can be followed (works for me, just needed to add `-lstdc++fs` to the end of my compile command, and everything works perfectly).